# Taking a variable out of object node js

Tags: node.js

I'm using this to get player's status in steam. I'm kinda new to Node.JS so that's why I'm kind of confused.

```
s.getPlayerSummaries({
        steamids: ['76561198152643711'],
        callback: function(err, data) {
               var myData = data["response"]["players"];
        }
});
```

which returns me

```
[ { steamid: '34264356456',
    gameextrainfo: 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive',
    gameid: '730' } ]
```

I tried using myData["gameid"] but that didn't work either. 
I also used json.stringify but when I do json.stringify(myData) and then take out gameid it returns me undefined. All I'm trying to do is take out these 3 veriables out of that object or array, idk tbh.

Comment: "which returns me" — what does? Is that the value of `myData`? Is it the return value of `s.getPlayerSummaries()`?

Comment: "I tried using myData["gameid"] but that didn't work either" — What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error message? Did you get an unexpected value?

Comment: "when I do json.stringify(myData)" — converting it into a string doesn't sound helpful

Comment: "then take out gameid" — What does "take out" mean in this context?

Comment: Quentin, when I do console.log(myData) that's half of what I get since that's non useful information here. When I used myData["gameid"] I got undefined in return which is because I was taking out the data wrong way. Yes, I tought  json.stringify(myData) would work but it gave me all data in a string but it would be a lot of work to find what I need. In "take out gameid" I mean return the veritable like var my = json.stringify(myData) and then make another var where I could return gameid.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving an array of objects but try to handle it as an object directly. Also you should use JSON.parse(data) if data is a string.

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(data); // step not needed if data is already an object/array
```

Once done you got that you need to retrieve your object that is the first element of your array.

```
var myObject = parsedArray[0]; // data[0] if data was not a string
```

Eventually to retrieve your object's `gameid` property you can do this:

```
var myGameId = myObject.gameid
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `myData` is an array of objects. So to read the first gameId in the array do

```
var firstGameId = myData[0].gameid;
```